# Disable scrolling zoom in google maps iframe

Tags: google-maps, iframe

So, apparently when I use:

```
<iframe style="pointer-events:none;" src="SOME GOOGLE MAPS LINK" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

the panning gets disabled as well.

and when I use:

```
<iframe style="scrollwheel: false" src="SOME GOOGLE MAPS LINK" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

it just deosn't work.

Is there anyway to just disable the scroll zoom in the iframe?

Comment: I just noticed that google fixed the scrolling behaviour - now the map view is fixed and a text is displayed of it, saying "you have to use cmd + to zoom :-)
great news for me!

Answer (score 42):

There are no way to disable scroll only on the Google Maps iframe API, but there is a work around.

As you had noticed that `style="pointer-events:none;"` does prevent the iframe from receiving any mouse event, and with the combination of Javascript event handlers on the overlay, you can disable and enable the receiving of mouse event at the time you want.

You can even listen to the `mousemove()` and only release the pointer events when the mouse are on certain areas (say, buttons)

I made a [quick demo](http://kylelam.github.io/iframe.html) on [github](https://github.com/kylelam/kylelam.github.io/blob/master/iframe.html), hope this help.

Comment: Work perfectly.

Comment: If you need to support any version of IE before 11, any solution relying on the pointer-events attribute will not work.

Answer (score 3):

For someone that wondering how to disable the **Javascript Google Map API**

Adopted from @kaho idea

```js
var map;
var element = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
function initMaps() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(element , {
    zoom: 17,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: {
      lat: parseFloat(-33.915916),
      lng: parseFloat(151.147159)
    },
  });
}


//START IMPORTANT part
//disable scrolling on a map (smoother UX)
jQuery('.map-container').on("mouseleave", function(){
  map.setOptions({ scrollwheel: false });
});
jQuery('.map-container').on("mousedown", function() {
  map.setOptions({ scrollwheel: true });
});
//END IMPORTANT part
```

```css
.big-placeholder {
  background-color: #1da261;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
      <div class="big-placeholder">
      </div>
      
      
      <!-- START IMPORTANT part -->
      <div class="map-container">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="min-height: 400px;"></div>  
      </div>
      <!-- END IMPORTANT part-->
      
      
      
      <div class="big-placeholder">
      </div>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIjN23OujC_NdFfvX4_AuoGBbkx7aHMf0&callback=initMaps">
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

He's a good blog post with how to achieve that with `onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"` [Disable the mouse scroll wheel zoom on embedded Google Map iframes](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-embedded-google-map-iframes/)

Comment: Please include the full code in your answers. Links to articles for the remainder of the answer may expire in time

Comment: If you need to support any version of IE before 11, any solution relying on the pointer-events attribute will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example

```
<script>
  function initMap() 
 {   
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),    
  {center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},     
  scrollwheel: false,    
  zoom: 8
  });
  }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer>      
</script>
```

Source:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?csw=1#GMap2.Methods